# Prove that $\phi(N_G(S))=N_{G'}(\phi(S))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let *G* and *G'* be groups and let $\phi: G \to G'$ be an isomorphism.Let *S* be a non empty subset of *G*.Given $a \in G$, let $aSa^{-1} = [asa^{-1}|s \in S]$. Let

$N_G(S) = [a \in G|aSa^{-1} = S]$ and $N_{G'}(\phi(S))= [a' \in G'| a'\phi(S)(a')^{-1} = \phi(S)]$

Prove that $\phi(N_G(S))=N_{G'}(\phi(S))$

I really have no idea where to start with this question since I don't know where I would use the ono to one and onto properties of the isomorphism,

Any guidance would really be appreciated

Thanks greatly

Comment: Use $\phi(x)\phi(S)\phi(x)^{-1} = \phi(xSx^{-1})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\forall\,y\in G'\,\;\exists\,x\in G\,\,s.t.\,\,\phi(x)=y\,\,\text{ so}\;\,\,\forall\,\,n\in N_G(S)\,\,\,\wedge\,\,\,\forall\; s\in S:$$

$$\phi(n)\phi(s)\phi(n)^{-1}=\phi(nsn^{-1})\in N_G'(\phi(S))$$

since $\,nsn^{-1}\in S\,$ because $\,n\in N_G(S)\;,\;\;s\in S\,$

From this it follows at once that $\,\phi(N_G(S))\subset N_G'(\phi(S))\,$ , and since $\,\phi\,$ is an isomorphism you can do the above with $\,\phi^{-1}\,$ and get the opposite containtment.